# hibernate @Entity on inner class only (top level class is not an @Entity)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, subclass, playframework-2.2

I would like to persist inner class into database. But it dosnt work.
Is there possibilty to do that? Or should i put that inner class into new plain file?
Now I am getting an error

```
 [IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: models.foo$bar]
```

My class file:

```
package models;
public class foo {
     @Required public String report;
     @Required public String reportType;


     @Entity
     public static class bar{
         @Required public int year;
         @Required public int month;

         public void toDataBase() {
                JPA.em().persist(this);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not a subclass. That's an inner class. And yes, you should make it a top-level class.

Comment: I've correct my post. So There is no other way to Map inner class with hibernate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting JPA 2.1 specification:

> The entity class must be a top-level class. An enum or interface must not be designated as an entity

You can download the spec from [this address](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html).
What can be mapped as an entity is as well pretty well described [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types).