# Inflate inner class in entity in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've entity and connected JPA repository. I need init main object and it's work for me but I can't inflate inner object in main entity. For example:

SQL:

```
select id, latitude, longitude from user where id = 1;
```

Struct:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
class User {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    Location location = new Location();
    public static class Location {
        @Column(name="latitude")
        double latitude;
        @Column(name="longitude")
        double longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hibernate @Entity on inner class only (top level class is not an @Entity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008424/hibernate-entity-on-inner-class-only-top-level-class-is-not-an-entity)

Comment: Add `@Embeddable` to Location class